# How to extract data from posts related to a specific research

Tags: python, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api

I'm really new to this Imm working on the Facebook Graph API in python. I am trying to get posts related to specific research.for example I made a research about Joe Biden like this image shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDjtb.jpg
my question is ist it possible to extract data from posts in this research URL like "User name" "Description" "Photo"...
if it is what methods can use

Comment: Where is the Facebook API Python code that you mention?

Comment: I still haven't write any code I'm just asking if it is possible, cause I made some research and all I found is people extracting data from someones profile not from research like this , so I wanted to ask if this even possible

Answer (score 0):

yes thats possible

also if u want to **scrape** send your link